# vector::erase() also erases member-vectors of a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

People, I am new to all this programming talk. Up until now it was quite easy to find answers by googling them but right here I have big trouble expressing what I want to ask, let me try: Erasing a vector calls the destructor before freeing the memory, right? Now how does a struct-vector react, if it is destructed? One does not define a destructor for these things, but is it correct to assume that if a struct is "destructed" each of its members' destructors will be called as well?

Let me give you an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct ding_t {
    std::string dang;
} foo;

strung boom_t {
    vector <ding_t> chuck;
} bar;

int main () {
    vector <boom_t> tom;
    tom.resize(10);
    tom[4].chuck.resize(5);
    tom[4].chuck[3].dang = "jerry";
    tom.erase();

    return 0;
}
```

in this case, will the memory allocated by

```
tom[4].chuck.resize(5);
```

be freed as well? Sorry for my vocabulary, but at this moment I am trying to move from pointers to the more sophisticated cpp language equivalent of vectors. I hope I got my point across. Thanks in advance guys and please just redirect me if this has already been asked, as I've said, I don't know how to circumscribe this question.

Comment: Adding a tag for the language you are working in will get you more attention. Sorry I can't answer your question. +1'd

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the memory will be freed automatically.

When a vector is destructed it will call the destructor of all the elements it contains. You didn't define a destructor for your `struct` so the compiler will provide a default one for you (that does nothing).

However if your vector contains pointers to objects it will be *your* responsibility to call the destructor on the objects before destructing the vector (because the vector will call the destructor of the *pointers*, not the pointed objects), if you have no other way to access them later.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.11 for the answer to your question and the entire article for a very good treatment of destructors in C++.

As to your second question: yes, the memory allocated by `tom[4].chuck.resize(5);` will get freed as well, since it is the **vector**'s responsibility to manage its own memory allocations (which is the case for the "resize()" call.)

Comment: Ah, the famous cpp FAQ, I didn't think of _that_. Thanks to all of you. This was really helpful. Now that I think about it I could have also resized and erased it in a loop and check if its memory usage increases over time.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Since you are not allocating the  Object dynamically with the  `new` operator, you dont have to deallocate them manually.
It's done automatically for you.

Ok. Back to your code :)

If you want to erase the 6th element then use `tom.erase (tom.begin()+5)` .

And if you want to erase all elements then use   `tom.erase (tom.begin(),tom.end() )` .

To erase the first 3 elements use `tom.erase (tom.begin(),tom.begin()+3)`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct ding_t 
{
    std::string dang;
} foo;

struct boom_t {
    std::vector <ding_t> chuck;
} bar;

int main () {
    vector <boom_t> tom;
    tom.resize(10);
    tom[4].chuck.resize(5);
    tom[4].chuck[3].dang = "jerry";

    //error C2661: 'erase' : no overloaded function takes 0 parameters
    //tom.erase( );

    // erase the 6th element
  tom.erase (tom.begin()+5);

    // erase the first 3 elements:
  //tom.erase (tom.begin(),tom.begin()+3);

    // erase everything:
  //tom.erase (tom.begin(),tom.end() );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've done this little check, just to make sure. (Why didn't I think of this earlier... was quite late yesterday... ) The initial code was badly written and didn't work, apologies for that.

This:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct ding_t {
    std::string dang;
} foo;

struct boom_t {
    std::vector <ding_t> chuck;
} bar;

int main () {
    std::vector <boom_t> tom;

    while (true) {
        tom.resize(10);
        tom[4].chuck.resize(5);
        tom[4].chuck[3].dang = "jerry";
        tom.erase( tom.begin(), tom.end() );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

causes no *memory leak*, the used memory is stable.